# C++ vscode extension doesn't see source relative paths

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I am writing cmake project and I am using there source-relative includes maid through `include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}`. It is building well by cmake, but VS Code intellisense extension doesn't see included files.

#### Errors

```
flag_parsce.cpp:
    cannot open source file "cfg/ConfigManager.h"
    name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name [Ln 14, co
    name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name [Ln 25, Col 34]
    identifier "FlagParseException" is undefined
```

#### Cmake build results

```
[main] Building folder: my_proj 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --build <${workspaceFolder}/build> --config Debug --target all --
[build] ninja: no work to do.
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:00.029
[build] Build finished with exit code 0
```

#### Project architecture

```
.
├── cfg
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── ConfigManager.cpp
│   └── ConfigManager.h
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp
└── src
    ├── DependencyGraph
    │   ├── DependencyGraph.cpp
    │   └── DependencyGraph.h
    ├── Exception
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   └── FlagParseException
    │       ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │       ├── FlagParseException.cpp
    │       └── FlagParseException.h
    └── staff
        └── flag_parse.cpp
```

#### The problem file

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include "cfg/ConfigManager.h"

void flag_parse(int argc, char** argv) {
    typedef std::function<void(std::string)> OneArgHandler;
    typedef std::function<void()> NoArgsHandler;
#define S(str, f)                                    \
    {                                                \
        str, [](const std::string& arg) { f = arg; } \
    }

    std::unordered_map<std::string, OneArgHandler> oneArg{
        S("-c", ConfigManager::CONFIG_FILE),
    };
#undef S
#define S(str, k, v)         \
    {                        \
        str, []() { k = v; } \
    }
    std::unordered_map<std::string, NoArgsHandler> noArgs{
    };

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (argv[i][0] != '-' && ConfigManager::ROOT_PATH == ""){
            continue;
        }
        auto noArgsFlag = noArgs.find(argv[i]);
        if (noArgsFlag != noArgs.end()) {
            (*noArgsFlag).second();
            continue;
        }
        auto oneArgFlag = oneArg.find(argv[i]);
        if (oneArgFlag == oneArg.end()) {
            throw FlagParseException(
                std::string("There is not such flag as \"") + argv[i] + "\"");
        }
        (*oneArgFlag).second(std::string(argv[i + 1]));
        i++;
    }
}
```

#### ./CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)
project(my_proj VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

add_subdirectory(src/Exception)
add_subdirectory(cfg)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Exception cfg)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

#### cfg/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(cfg ConfigManager.h ConfigManager.cpp)
```

#### .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "CMake",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: The cmake extension does this all for you.

Comment: I had already installed cmake extension, but the problem is that intellisense doesn't see my files. Cmake compiles project prefectly

Comment: where's the part where you register flag_parse.cpp as a source file of a CMake target? Or do you not do that? If you don't, why don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` file, pressing ctrl+shift+p, typing in "CMake: Configure", hitting enter and choosing a compiler fixed the problem for me.
Make sure you've got the CMake extension installed in VSCode beforehand.